# Migrating to the FusionTables v1 API

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I am starting to migrate an app built on the earlier version of the fusiontables API to the v1 version of the API. And am coming up with a whole bunch of questions on the upgrade. Hope someone can help with answers.

1) My web application makes requests to the fusiontables API on behalf of the user of the web application. Currently, I have an OAuth token and an OAuth token secret that I use to make OAuth authenticated requests with for my fusiontables query URLs. I currently the libraries from here http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables-client-libraries/ . The OAuth2 upgrade docs expect me to use the google provided library to make the request which seem to be using collections and things in the client API. But, I do not want to make a lot of changes to the current code base. How can i upgrade my app to use OAuth2 with as little change as possible? I am thinking that this approach is best for my app? https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount is that correct?

2) Also, the tokens obtained via OAuth2 expire every hour, is there a way to obtain an OAuth2 token that doesn't expire?

3) Also, how do you use the refresh tokens? I can't find any docs on it.

4) How does google's OAuth 2.0 playground web app manage to get access and refresh token without the client ids and the private key?

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer all your questions

1. The approach with the Service Account is useful if you don't want to access resources of the user, but only your own tables. The service account is just a user under your control. If you actually want to access tables of an actual user that uses your application, the service account is not really an option. You'll better look into the whole OAuth 2.0 stuff. I don't think that adding the Google API client is a big change, it's only a library and you need add maybe 5 lines to your code.
2. see answer 3.
3. The process is [described in the OAuth guide](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#installed), you get a refresh token from Google, which does not expire, and using this token you can always get a valid access token.
4. The playground asks for your credentials, that's how it gets access :)

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate the response.  1) I do need to access my own account. The service account scenario fits what it want to do. My question is the Google OAuth2 client libraries seems to want you to use their 'build' method with their api name and version to use their libraries. I have already written my application from earlier to use querystring etc for querying fusiontables. What is the best way to update my codebase for OAuth2?  2) I am looking for code samples on how to use the refresh tokens 3) What kind of access does it do service account/web client etc?

Comment: Here is an [PHP example of mine with a Service Account](https://github.com/odi86/GFTPrototype/blob/master/examples/php/UpdateTable.php). If you use this approach you don't need access or refresh tokens. But if you want to use it for a different scenario here is a [description how to get a new access token using a refresh token](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#refresh).

Answer (score 0):

Answer to questions #4 above "How does google's OAuth 2.0 playground web app manage to get access and refresh token without the client ids and the private key?"...Google did a short video on how to do this.

[4 minute video how to set up OAuth Playground for clientID and Secret key](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfWe1gPCnzc)